# Is it possible to see your ping?

Tags: splatoon-2

Sometimes, it seems that I'm desynced with the server.

Things like I'll be hit by things that clearly were going next to me or picking up an egg half a second after touching it.

I would guess I have a high ping, but I don't seem to have a way to check.

So is there a way to check the ping in Splatoon 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, no. Plus, there's no dedicated server associated with Splatoon 2 (this game uses P2P connection), so that means your ping value will vary depending on the host.

However, there's something you can do:

- Buy a Switch dock for OLED version ([Black](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/dock-oled-model-black-116470/), [White](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/dock-oled-model-white-116471/)). This allows you to connect with LAN cable, so if you have unused LAN cable around you, this is where you'd use it.
- Place your Switch near the Wi-fi router (if it already isn't). Many things can interrupt Wi-fi radio wave, resulting in packet loss and lower speeds.